# После запуска manage.py runserver открывается консоль и сразу закрывается

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при запуске `django` проекта открывается `cmd` консоль (не в `pycharm`) и сразу закрывается, понятно что закрывается скорее всего из-за ошибки, но ошибку я не могу посмотреть т.к. все очень быстро происходит, на другом пк проект запускался в терминале `pycharm`, можете подсказать, как мне сделать так, чтобы `django` запускался в терминале `pychram`, а не в отдельном окне `cmd` консоли?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Открой cmd. Перейди в каталог с проектом. Попробуй запустить

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/813788)

Comment: Проблема CMD  закрывается. Ответ соответствует вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема с запуском сервера. (.\manage.py runserver).
И сервер запускался в новом окне. Чтобы вывод был в терминал нужно так: python .\manage.py runserver